# Uploading Profile Picture/Avatar Error using image_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and I am working on a rails application. I have a user account created using `devise` gem. I have altered the `devise/registrations/edit` to allow the user to change the default profile picture. However, when I upload an image on edit, it only shows the image error icon. I have changed the permitted parameters in devise to allow the avatar as well.

I have also used the image on the navigation bar, it only shows the error image.
My navbar has the following added for the image:
`<%= image_tag user_avatar(current_user,40), class: "rounded-circle" %>`

and my `application_helper.rb` has the following code:

```
def user_avatar(user, size=50)
    if user.avatar.attached? 
      user.avatar.variant(resize: "#{size}×#{size}!")
    else
      image_tag 'default_avatar.png', size: size
    end
  end
```

and this is what it looks like in `edit.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <%= image_tag user_avatar(resource, 100) %>
          </div>
   </div>
```

This is how it appears:
[image: image of my navbar after uploading a profile picture]

I used a tutorial to get this.
Can someone tell my why this image error appears?

Answer (score 0):

in your #Gemfile
`gem 'mini_magick'`

Then on Your helper

```
def user_avatar(user, size=50)
  if user.avatar.attached? 
    user.avatar.attachment.variant(resize: "#{size}×#{size}!")
  else
   'default_avatar.png'
  end
end
```

Also, You don't need image_tag again in helper for default image, just return the url.

Comment: Hi thanks! But it did not work. I have added a picture of the scenario above. The default image appears, only the newly uploaded images doesnt show.

Answer (score 0):

@Iosh Did you install image magick on your system? The gem talks to the system executable. In order to manipulate the size of the image, you will need to have the executable(Image Magick) installed on your system.

Check if it is installed by typing the following at the command prompt (Terminal).

```
which magick
```

if it is installed, you should get a path to the executable.
If it is NOT installed, you will get a 'not found' reply.

check the website for installation instruction
https://imagemagick.org